# How to change inline code in visual composer?

Tags: css, wordpress, inline, visual-composer

I can't change inline code for visual composer 
please help me , I want edit `right:49.5px;` to `left:49.5px;`

```css
element {
    right: 49.5px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 1349px;
    padding-left: 49.5px;
    padding-right: 49.5px;
}
```

```html
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1557482154450 vc_row-has-fill" style="right: 49.5px; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1349px; padding-left: 49.5px; padding-right: 49.5px;">
```

Comment: add a class to row and write css for that class in style.css

Comment: I did this, but the inline code is in the top priority

Comment: you can add `!important` ?

Comment: Yes, I added, but still the inline style is a priority

Comment: you need to add parent classes like `.firstparentclass  .secondparentclass  element {`

Answer (score 0):

```
.demoClass{
    right: 49.5px!important;
    position: relative !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    width: 1349px !important;
    padding-left: 49.5px !important;
    padding-right: 49.5px !important;
}
```

There is an option `Extra class name` to set custom css class in visual composer.  In the option field set this demoClass and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the code, don't forget to clear the site and server cache.